# php mysql if else update database and display different links based on database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am learning php and I am trying to add some buttons that modify the status of a project. I managed to make my code do this and it's working but I am sure it can be written better and I wonder if this can be done without refreshing the page? Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$status = (int)$_GET['status'];
$statusSql = "UPDATE projects SET status = '$status' WHERE id ='$id'";
$db->query($statusSql);
header('Location: projects.php');
}
........
<?php
      if(($project['status']) == 0 ) {
         echo "<a href='projects.php?status=1&id={$project['id']}' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'>
           <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span>
           </a>&nbsp New Project";
      }elseif(($project['status']) == 1 ){
         echo "<a href='projects.php?status=2&id={$project['id']}' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pause'></span>
          </a>&nbsp In Progress &nbsp<a href='projects.php?status=3&id={$project['id']}' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'>
           <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-stop'></span>
           </a>";
      }elseif(($project['status']) == 2 ){
        echo "<a href='projects.php?status=1&id={$project['id']}' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span>
         </a>&nbsp On Hold</span>
          </a>";
      }elseif(($project['status']) == 3 ){
        echo "<a href='projects.php?status=1&id={$project['id']}' class='btn btn-xs btn-default'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></span>
         </a>&nbsp Finished</span>
          </a>";
      };
```

?>

Comment: Without page refresh look into using AJAX requests...https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Few things, for dynamic pages, as @PhpDude said, you'd want to learn  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) and [AJAX](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/). Since you're using `$db->query(...);` i'm assuming you're using `mysqli`, i'd give a try at [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, and learn about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).